# Dota2 reborn download keeps restarting

Tags: steam, dota-2

I've been downloading Dota2 reborn and when it reached nearly 55% I exited Steam as I had to download another program. When I reopened Steam  the download starts again from 0% and due to my slow internet connection it would take like 3 hours to reach 55%. So is there any way to resume the download where I left off?

Comment: best option is, if you have friend who have downloaded the game then copy the file from his pc/lappy and paste in your folder..more detail do google..

Comment: I dont have any friend who plays dota

Comment: Unfortunately steam can't resume the download where you left off. You need to leave steam open when it's downloading the game

Comment: Does '**check file integrity**' work for incompletely downloaded games? You could give that a try.

Answer (score -1):

Steam resumes your downloads regardless when and how you interrupt it. Restarting at 0% is an error. Try to cleanout the DOTA2 steam directory and start your download. Stop it at lets say 5% and than resume it. See if you can resume. If this doesn't work I would probably reinstall steam or ask steam support. Resuming downloads is a basic feature of steam.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have to worry the 0% is the 0 from 55 it is going to continue from 55 but shows as 0.